# Activemq pauses other application in mule standalone

Tags: activemq-classic, mule

I have deployed two application in my mule standalone in which one application requires ActiveMQ up and running because I have applied reconnect-forever policy for connection.

but without starting ActiveMQ broker if i start mule.bat file it doesn't even deploy other applications which are not dependent on ActiveMQ.

What can be done to solve this issue so that only ActiveMQ dependent applications wait for the connection and other application start working.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `blocking="false"` in the reconnect?

Comment: nope i have set blocking = "true" because if i set it to false even my application doesnt wait for the reconnection

Comment: The 'blocking' attribute establishes whether the application needs to wait or not until it was able to connect to the broker.
You have to it to false and also set a reconnection strategy so the connector can connect in a future attempt.

Comment: oh k thanks for the suggestion i'll try dis n get back with the behaviour :)